# How to add color to voronoi diagram based on certain value in d3.js

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js

I have stuck by this problem for the last two days, and it's time for me to ask...

Basically I've successfully draw the voronoi diagram on a map based on a .csv file look like this:

```
salaryLevel, lat, lon
-0.263031898    -1.957862   30.058205
-0.263031898    -1.960236   30.018172
0.510327701 -1.979509   30.044363
0.510327701 -1.919366   30.046766
0.510327701 -1.900015   30.034252
0.510327701 -1.926512   30.08714
-0.263031898    -1.923729   30.072793
0.510327701 -1.938892   30.07126
0.510327701 -1.950085   30.079418
```

Now I'm trying to add color the each section of the map based on the value of salary level as shown above. So basically for salary level between -1-0, using blue, between 0-0.5, using green, something like that. Here is the code I have for now:

```
  var vertices = salary.map(function(d) { return [+d.lon, +d.lat]; });
  var median = salary.forEach(function(d) { d.median = +d.salaryLevel; });
  var voronoi = d3.geom.voronoi()
      .clipExtent([0, 0], [width, height]);

  var max = d3.max(median, function(d) { return d; });
  var min = d3.min(median, function(d) { return d; });
  var color = d3.scale.quantize().domain([min, max]).range([0, 0.1, 0.3]);

  layer4.selectAll("path")
     .data(voronoi(vertices))
   .enter().append("svg:path")
     .classed("voronoi", true)
     .attr("d", function(d) { return "M" + d.map(function(d) { return projection([d[0], d[1]]); }).join("L") + "Z"; });
```

I didn't find out a solution for the last two days, can someone help me? Thank you so much!

Comment: *"... I'm trying to add color ..."* — I can't see any evidence of this in your code. What have you tried so far? *"... as shown in the picture."* — what picture?

Comment: @squeamishossifrage I'm not able to post pictures, so I pasted the .csv instead. I edited the code above. I tried to segment the salary level by 0, 0.1, 0.3, and the add color accordingly. My problem now is to match the salary level with the coordinates. I'm new to d3.js, wondering whether this works? or there are better solutions? Thanks!

Comment: That's a .tsv file, dude.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an example where color is added to a voronoi diagram.  Basically you will create three css classes with fill values for the 3 different colors.

Then do something similar to what they do in the redraw() function, except where they do a simple modulus to choose the color, you'll do a test to see what range your data value falls in.

http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4060366